# Java Exception related to web-service call

Tags: java, web-services, exception, soap

I don't have any knowledge of web-services, but I am asked to fix an issue related to web-service.

I get the following exception when I run my program :

> org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapBodyException: Could not access envelope: Parser has already reached end of the document. No siblings found; nested exception is org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: Parser has already reached end of the document. No siblings found

Where should I look to fix the problem ? I looked into the java-docs of those exceptions, but no useful information is given there .

Any links to learn about the basics of these things will be useful.

Comment: Hope you know Soap UI. Can you try accessing the service using soap UI and see if the response is coming properly..

Comment: hmm..I don't know soap UI either.

Comment: Download it then. Use the trial version.. Pretty self explanatory.. when ever working with web-servivce Soap UI is a damn useful tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using soapUI 4.0.1 download it from their site http://www.soapui.org/

This will give you the response in a GUI and will help you to find the issue.